# C# file upload: no groups from reg ex?

Tags: c#, regex, file, upload

this code was working fine till this morning, can anyone spot my mistake? probably really silly but it has me stumped!

i use a form to submit a file (field name 'fileUpEx'), and then i wrote a class to upload it (like i said, it's been working for ages)....
(if i write 'filepath' to the page it is 'Test copy.pdf')
My class returns 'no groups'!!!
Very odd, can anyone please help?

```
string filepath = fileUpEx.PostedFile.FileName;
string pat = @"\\(?:.+)\\(.+)\.(.+)";
Regex r = new Regex(pat);
Match m = r.Match(filepath);
if (m.Groups[0].Captures.Count != 0)
{ 
   //blaa blaa blaa
}
else 
{
   return "no Groups";
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Vauneen

Comment: The string `"Test copy.pdf"` of course won't match your regex... Please `Console.WriteLine(filepath)` to see its actual content.

Comment: Care to explain the regex - you seem to expect a UNC filename?! What is `fileUpEx.PostedFile.FileName` when this fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression requires that the file path contains a backslash which it doesn't. You could perhaps make that part optional, for example:

```
@"(?:\\.+\\)?(.+)\.(.+)"
```

Alternatively you could use the methods available in [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx):

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
string filename = Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension(filePath);
```